# Имитирование checked

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть у меня на странице checkbox и вот допустим когда страница загрузилась мне нужно что бы он как бы на жался, простая подстановка атрибута ничего не даст так как нужно запустить функции которые закреплены за checkbox. Я пробовал

```
$('.checkbox').trigger('change');
$('.checkbox').trigger('click');
$('.checkbox').change();
```

но не один из методов не работает.

Comment: а нельзя просто добавить к чекбоксу атрибут checked?

Comment: `$('.checkbox').prop('checked', true)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для определения\установения `checked` НЕИСПОЛЬЗУЙТЕ что-либо кроме `.prop()`.

Подробнее о  [`.prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)

```js
$('input[type="button"').on('click',function(){
  $('.onload').each(function(){// Переберём
    var thisProp = $(this).prop('checked'); // вернёт true - если "выбран", ну и false если нет.
    $(this).prop('checked', thisProp ? false : true); // Инвертируем значение.
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- ----------------------------- -->
<input type="checkbox"> - изначально ВЫКЛ<br>
<input type="checkbox" checked> - изначально ВКЛ<br>
<input class="onload" type="checkbox"> - изначально ВЫКЛ, после загрузки ВКЛ<br>
<input class="onload" type="checkbox" checked> - изначально ВКЛ, после загрузки ВЫКЛ
<br><br><br><br>
В примере, вместо загрузки страницы, будем использовать эту кнопку.<br>
<input type="button" value="типо загрузим страницу">
```